"don't allow" audio device via command line
I would like to be able to "allow" or "don't allow" (note that this is different from enable/disable hardware) the output/input audio devices via command line or by modifying some registry key.
The OS is Windows 11 and the "allow/don't allow" referred above is visible via: Settings > Sound > All sound devices > device > Allow/Don't allow.
Also, Settings > Sound > More sound settings > device > Properties > Device usage = Don't use this device (disable) would be an option.
Are you aware of any way to do this?

Please clarify WHY you do not wish to enable/disable devices? Unless Windows (or the driver) offers a method for allow/disallow you're out of luck, no matter how much you want to be in luck. I believe the "Don't use" option you mention is a proxy for Enable/Disable.

Also, what research have you done so far and what have you tried?

You could google for "powershell disable sound device" or "nircmd disable sound device".

andrewMorton: I did my internet search but it all leads to disable/enable hardware instead of "allow/not allow"; thus, i'm asking for help. Maybe you found something that works that you can share?
musc2myear: all things I tried, ended up enabling/disabling the device. Also, a simple test shows me that is not just a proxy as the device does not appear "disabled" in the device manager mmc, instead, it dissapears.
